# Como saber el tiempo faltante en minutos con valores timestamp, javascript?

Tags: javascript, timestamp

Como saber el valor en minutos de una diferencia de timestamp.

Actualmente poseo 2 fechas con su timestamp, una que india la fecha y hora actual
y la otra que tiene una hora mas a la fecha actual.

```
var ultima_fecha_vecimiento = 0
for(let i in ultimoHistorial){
     ultima_fecha_vecimiento = ultimoHistorial[i].ultima_fecha_vecimiento; //Contiene una hora mas a la fecha actual, es decir una fecha superior.
}
firebase.database().ref('/.info/serverTimeOffset')
  .once('value')
  .then(function stv(data) {
     vm.horario_firebase = data.val() + Date.now(); //Contien la fecha actual
     let tiempo_faltante  = vm.horario_firebase - ultima_fecha_vecimiento;
     console.log("ESTE ES EL TIEMPO QUE LE FALTA AL CRONOMETRO");
     console.log(tiempo_faltante); //Aca obtengo la diferencia de los timestamp
});
```

Esa diferencia de timestamp como la puedo convertir a minutos,
de tal forma que me indique cuando tiempo me falta por alcanzar la fecha que se encuentra almacenada en la variable `ultima_fecha_vecimiento`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las fechas en Javascript se guardan en milisegundos transcurridos desde el **1ro de enero de 1970 a las 00:00:00 UTC**.

Así que cuando restas dos fechas obtienes la cantidad de milisegundos de diferencia entre ellas.

Ejemplo:

```
const ayer3pm = new Date(2019, 3, 18, 15, 0, 0, 0);
const hoy3pm = new Date(2019, 3, 19, 15, 0, 0, 0);
const delta = hoy3pm - ayer3pm;

delta = 86400000.
```

Como ves, delta es 86400000 que es la cantidad de milisegundos que tiene un dia (desde hoy a las 15:00 hrs hasta ayer a la misma hora).

Para convertir a minutos solo debes dividir entre 60000. O sea 1000 para llevar a segundos y 60 para llevar a minutos.

```
const minutosTranscurridos = delta/60000; // Muestra: -> 1440
```

Esto por supuesto es aplicable si sabes que no te interesa lidiar con diferencias de tiempo, cambios de hora por horarios de verano y toda la complejidad inherente a las fechas/horas en cualquier lenguaje de programación. En caso de que quieras algo más potente puedes echarle un vistazo a moment.js.

Te dejo el link por acá: https://momentjs.com

Espero te sirva.